# Shell script: Pass associative array to another shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to pass associate array as a single argument to shell script.

mainshellscript.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A cmdOptions=( [branch]=testing [directory]=someDir [function1key]=function1value [function1key]=function1value )
./anothershellscript.sh cmdOptions
```

anothershellscript.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
#--- first approach, didn't work, shows error "declare: : not found"
#opts=$(declare -p "$1")
#declare -A optsArr=${opts#*=}
#---
# second approach, didnt work, output - declare -A optsArr=([0]="" )
#declare -A newArr="${1#*=}"
#declare -p newArr
#---
```

I'm suspecting that they way I am collecting array in anothershellscript.sh is wrong, I'm finding a way to access map values simply by providing `echo "${optsArr[branch]}"` shall give `testing`.

I am using bash version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys).

Comment: Is "anotherscript" something you can `source` rather then execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Passing Associative array to sub script

Associative arrays and regular arrays are not well exported. But you could pass variables by using `declare -p` in some *wrapper* call.

First script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A cmdOptions=( [branch]=testing     [function1key]=function1value
                        [directory]=someDir  [function2key]=function2value )
declare -a someArray=( foo "bar baz" )

declare -x someVariable="Foo bar baz"    # Using *export* for simple variables

bash -c "$(declare -p cmdOptions someArray someVariable);. anothershellscript.sh"
```

Note syntax `. anothershellscript.sh` could be replaced by `source anothershellscript.sh`.

Doing so, prevent need of temporary files or temporary variable and keep *STDIN/STDOUT* free.

Then your *`anothershellscript.sh`* could use your variables as is.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -p cmdOptions someArray someVariable
```

could work.

Answer (score 4):

Processes are separate - they *do not* share variables. A variable set in one process is not visible in the other process. Except: child processes *inherit* exported variables, but `cmdOptions` is not exported and you can't export associative arrays anyway.

So pass the *string representation of the array* to the child, either via arguments or with a file or with an exported variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A cmdOptions=( [branch]=testing [directory]=someDir [function1key]=function1value [function1key]=function1value )

export SOME_VAR="$(declare -p cmdOptions)"              # env or
declare -p cmdOptions > some_file.txt                   # file or
./anothershellscript.sh "$(declare -p cmdOptions)"      # arg
# Note - `declare -p` is called _on parent side_!
```

Then load in the child:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A newArr="${SOME_VAR#*=}"      # env or
. some_file.txt                         # file or
declare -A newArr="${1#*=}"             # arg

# How to load from file so that current environment is not affected:
tmp=$(
   . some_file.txt
   declare -p cmdOptions
)
declare -A newArr=${tmp#*=}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to rebuild that array in second script, here is an example script1:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A test=(
    [v1]=1
    [v2]=2
    [v3]=3
)

for key in "${!test[@]}"; { data+=" $key=${test[$key]}"; }
echo "$data" | ./test2
```

script2:

```
#!/bin/bash
read   -ra data
declare -A test2

for item in "${data[@]}"; {
    key="${item%=*}"
    val="${item#*=}"
    test2[$key]="$val"
}
echo "${test2[@]}"
```