# Bash: A technique to pass variable contents as such to `bash -c`

Tags: bash, escaping, sh

Suppose I have a bash variable `ext`. I would like to do (something like) `bash -c "internal=$ext"`, where `internal` has the exact same contents as `ext`

- `bash -c "internal=$ext"` will not work if `ext` has spaces inside. Moreover, code injection is also possible. `ext="a b"` will try to execute `b`
- `bash -c "internal='$ext'"` will also not work if `ext` has a (single) quote. For instance, `ext="'"` will fail
- `bash -c "internal=\"$ext\""` will also not work if `ext` has a (double) quote. For instance, `ext='"'` will fail

I'd ideally like a technique that would work every possible string, and the contents of `internal` and `ext` to be exactly equal.

One possible solution is an *out of band* solution, where you can use the environment / some file to store `ext` and read from there. For instance, `export ext ; bash -c "internal=\"\$ext\'"` might work...

I'd not like to use this technique. This is because it might work for `bash -c`, it will fail for things like `ssh`, etc.

How can one go about this? Is there some existing function / command that can automatically escape the appropriate characters in `ext`?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `bash -c 'internal="$1"' _ "$ext"`?

Comment: The command given to `bash -c` can accept arguments like a script would, except that you have to manually specify the value of `$0` (thus the underscore above). Arguments are a safe way to pass arbitrary data to a program.

Comment: @tjm3772, That does seem like a good idea, however, I'm curious to know how it'd generalize to other commands such as `ssh`, `parallel`, `tmux`, etc. which internally call something like `bash -c`

Comment: The are some duplicate on this question: [How to pass an array argument to the Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75033037/1765658), [Pass associative array to another shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65342558/1765658)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, there does seem to exist a command that does this automatic escaping for us! It is `printf %q`.

Here's how that would work:

```
ext=$(cat << "EOF"
This is a wonky string
t"'x?/?''$(
# This is a comment
> >
EOF
)

# Save escaped text to variable
printf -v escaped_ext %q "$ext"

bash -c "int=$escaped_ext ; echo \"\$int\""
```

Comment: You can also use `printf -v var` to assign to variables.

Comment: If you've got Bash 4.4 (released in 2016) or later than you can use `bash -c "int=${ext@Q}; declare -p int"`.  Search for *parameter@operator* in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Answer (score 2):

Standard POSIX shell grammar provides everything you need to pass variables or values to an inline shell script without any escaping or quoting black magic.

A couple options:

Pass variable as global environment:

```bash
export ext='Hello World!'
bash -xc 'internal="$ext"; printf "%s\\n" "$internal"'
```

```
+ internal='Hello World!'
+ printf '%s\n' 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
```

Pass variable as inline environment:

```bash
ext='Hello World!' bash -xc 'internal="$ext"; printf "%s\\n" "$internal"'
```

```
+ internal='Hello World!'
+ printf '%s\n' 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
```

Pass variable value as argument:

```bash
ext='Hello World!'
bash -xc 'internal="$1"; printf "%s\\n" "$internal"' _ "$ext"
```

```
+ internal='Hello World!'
+ printf '%s\n' 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
```

**EDIT**
Now if what you really need is a way to expand the variable value into an inline script that's going to work with ssh or other downstream processor. Don't forget to read this popular question: [Passing variables in remote ssh command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314660/7939871)

Modern Bash interpreters have an `@Q` special expansion parameter to quote or escape a value.

Bash's expand quoted `${var@Q}`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ext='Hello World!'
bash -xc "internal=${ext@Q}; printf '%s\n' \"\$internal\""
```

```
+ internal='Hello World!'
+ printf '%s\n' 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
```

Comment: I already mentioned the environment variable approach (and potential limitation) in my question. I'd like my technique to work with not just `bash -c`, but other natural commands like `tmux`, `ssh`, `parallel`, etc., which is why I'd like to avoid these _out of band_ techniques.

Comment: It might be even better to let `internal` itself be the environment variable, assuming the user has control over the script passed via `-c`.

Comment: @SuraajKS Here you are with a fourth method that expands quoted value.

Comment: Or this: `internal='Hello World!';bash -xc "$(declare -p internal)"';printf "%s\\n" "$internal"'`

Comment: Note that `${variable@Q}` requires Bash 5.0 or later. AFAIK Mac OSX *still* only ships with Bash 3.2 (OSX users should use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install Bash 5).

Comment: Or even `bash --noprofile --rcfile <(declare -p internal) -xic 'printf "%s\\n" "$internal"'`

Comment: @amphetamachine, `${var@Q}` was introduced in Bash 4.4 (2016).  See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061.

Comment: Note that quotes are unnecessary when setting variables using `foo=$bar` syntax, regardless of the content of `$bar`.

Comment: @amphetamachine Does not apply here because the expansion is performed during the actual script creation (not during execution of the inline script). The trace option `-x` is here to tell you the executed statement is `internal='Hello World!'` and this would not be ok to assign a literal value with a space in it without quotes or escaping spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is regarded as cheating, but I would simply do a

```
internal=$ext bash -c ' whatever you want to execute here '
```

Different to your approach, where `internal` is just a *shell variable* inside the bash command, my approach would make it an **environment** variable.

Comment: I already mention this approach in the question :)

Comment: @SuraajKS : Not exactly. In your question, the assignment to `internal` always happens within the argument passed with `-c`, while in my approach, it happens before the `bash` process is started.

Answer (score 0):

## Using a File Descriptor

In addition to the environment variable method described in your question, you can also use `declare -p` to print shell variables then read them in using a handle:

```bash
external1=(foo bar baz)
external2='qux'
bash -c 'eval "$(cat <&5)"; echo "external1 is ${external1[*]}, external2 is $external2"' 5< <(declare -p external1 external2)
```

In addition to NOT polluting the global environment variable space, this *also* supports any variable type Bash supports, including lists and associative arrays.

## Alternate: Using an Argument

If you don't want to use a file descriptor, you can also pass the dynamic filename in as an argument:

```bash
bash -c 'VAR_FILE=$1; shift; eval "$(<"$VAR_FILE")"; ...' _ <(declare -p external1 external2)
```

*`<(command list)` is a Bash feature that sets up a temporary [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) (named pipe) that when read will contain the output from `command list`. The `<(...)` is replaced with `/dev/fd/[NUMBER]`.*

Comment: Why `eval` ?? !!!

Comment: Because in this case, it's safe. `declare -p` gives safe, properly-escaped variable declaration code (including type information). I myself do prefer the environment variable method, but OP was insistent it was not to be used.

Comment: But why? `bash <(declare -p variable;cat <<"eof" ... printf $variable ... eof ..)` could do the job and don't use eval.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub But you're still piping into bash, effectively evaluating a generated string. There's no security to be gained from your answer. Pipe string to bash = using `eval` on that string inside of bash.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Actually the code in your suggestion introduces more issues 1. You're evaluating a bigger string. 2. You're using `printf` without a pattern (variable could contain `%` patterns and screw things up). 3. The value of `$variable` could contain backticks and escapes really messing up your day.